# Window animation scale of 0.25 on OxygenOS 5.0.4?

Tags: user-interface, oxygenos

Is it possible to set the window animation scale to 0.25 on OxygenOS 5.0.4? The closest options I see are 0.0 and 0.5, but I'm hoping there would be a way to do this with root access.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't option in developer settings for that value of animation scale then there is [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zacharee1.systemuituner) app. App doesn't require root but you'll have to grant some permissions via ADB, you have guide how to do that when you launch app.
Now when you do that under miscellaneous section there are animation speeds where you can set it to any value you want. Keep in mind that when you restart the device in most cases all modifications you made with app and permissions you granted are gone so you'll need to do it again. I say in most cases because to me sometimes happened that everything is fine and sometimes I needed to do it again.

Comment: +1 thanks! I actually just found another one but this looks great too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [jOnePlus Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.jroot3d.joneplustools&hl=en) can do this.